# Macbook not charging after depleting battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

OK, this is a bit of a weird one.  My wife, thinking someone damaged her Macbook's cable, unplugged it.  She then ran the Macbook until it shut down by itself.  When I got home, I tested the cable and it checked out fine, except that the light wouldn't come on when I plug it in (the first time, the green light lit up briefly, but never since).

I'm at a loss as to how to fix this.  The Macbook doesn't turn on, so no way to get system information or reset SMC.  I do know it's an A1278, probably from around 2011/2.  I've cleaned the contacts on both the cable and the Macbook.  Also, unplugged and reconnected the battery.  So far, no joy.  Any ideas/suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: if you have a volt meter measure between pin 2 and 4 on the plug (18 Volt DC)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean on the plug that connects to the Macbook - did that, got no reading except a polarity change (Voltmeter set to 20VDC).  Checked the cable on the AC side for continuity - all OK.  Didn't check the DC side, as that was replaced about two months ago and it worked fine till now.

Comment: Since you already did the measurement and there is no Voltage on the magsafe plug, what would you say is wrong.

Comment: No voltage would indicate a problem with the actual adapter "box".  What confuses me is that I've read somewhere that there's some communication that takes place between the adapter and the Macbook, through the Magsafe connector.  This led me to wonder if this "handshake" still takes place, if the battery is completely drained?

Comment: It could also be worn out pins on the Macbook's side, or I'll have to reopen the adapter box.

Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Comment: So your charger is NOT working ! The handshake takes place since battery keeps reserve charge for its build in circuit. If you do not measure anything on the magsafe plug site the charger is not working

Comment: Thanks, that implies ripping the box open.  Do you happen to know which components typically fail?
I'll make a note that the battery keeps a reserve, then next time I can sound a little less stupid ;)

Comment: Battery is SMART battery. What makes it SMART is a integrated circuit (Chip mounted on the battery) that contains information that it uses to communicate with your Mac.  For example (among other) it contains the number of cycle counts, so when you move a battery from one Mac to another it still knows how old is it. I do not know anything about repairing Apple chargers.

Comment: Hypothesizing what happened.  A complete empty battery drew a maximum current from the charger for prolonged time. Charger did not survive that.